# Sign the exe file using NSIS script

Tags: exe, nsis, code-signing

I am using NSIS script to generate the exe file.

Now i have to sign the exe and what i am doing is using NSIS , create the exe file first. Then i open the command prompt in admin mode and run  the Signtool.exe file along with parameters like path to pfx file, timestamp url etc  to sign the exe and its getting signed without any issues

But i found that using [Finalize http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter5.html#finalize](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter5.html#finalize) in NSIS we can call the Signtool command from NSIS script itself

So for doing do i tried to make a .bat file with code for Signing the exe in it and saved the bat file in the same location of nsis script and i called this line of code in  the end

```
 !finalize 'signfile.bat'
```

But this resulted in  the below message

> Finalize command: signfile.bat 'signfile.bat' is not recognized as
>   an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
>   Finalize command returned 1

I tried with direct signing like below

```
 Signtool.exe sign /f k:\---.pfx /p ????? /tr http://timestamp.----.com /td sha256 /fd sha256 "%1"
```

and

```
Signtool.exe sign /f k:\--.pfx /p ????? /tr http://timestamp.---.com /td sha256 /fd sha256 filename.exe
```

Then i  get this error

!finalize expects 1-3 parameters, got 13.
Usage: !finalize command_with_%1 []

So anyone can helps to find out the proper syntax to use for signing the exe file from nsis script directly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message you get when running the .bat is from cmd.exe because it cannot find the file. You could try `!finalize dir` to find out what the current directory actually is.

The quote syntax is `!finalize '"c:\path\to\app.exe" "par am 1" param2 "par am 3"'`